# Find a specific char in an array of chars

Tags: string, blackberry, java-me, char

I am doing an application where I want to find a specific char in an array of chars. In other words, I have the following char array:

```
char[] charArray= new char[] {'\uE001', '\uE002', '\uE003', '\uE004', '\uE005', '\uE006', '\uE007', '\uE008', '\uE009'};
```

At some point, I want to check if the character `'\uE002'` exists in the `charArray`. My method was to make a loop on every character in the `charArray` and find if it exists.

```
for (int z = 0 ; z < charArray; z ++) {
    if (charArray[z] == myChar) {
        //Do the work
    }
}
```

Is there any other solution than making a char array and finding the character by looping every single char?

Comment: Only hash can do this quicker. But if your char array is not larger then  10000 chars, this char-by-char check should be done reasonably quick.

Comment: Are either the char or the array constant, in the simple sense of not ever changing?  Or even not changing very often?

Comment: What are your priorities?  Are you looking for a lot faster, or simpler, or...?

Comment: Lot faster. Here I have 10 characters. I want to implement 500 characters. That will become too slow I guess

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to pre-[sort](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28char%5B%5D%29) `charArray` and use [`Arrays.binarySearch(charArray, myChar)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28char%5B%5D,%20char%29). A non-negative return value will indicate that `myChar` is present in `charArray`.

```
char[] charArray = new char[] {'\uE001', '\uE002', '\uE003', '\uE004', '\uE005', '\uE006', '\uE007', '\uE008', '\uE009'};
Arrays.sort(charArray); // can be omitted if you know that the values are already sorted
...
if (Arrays.binarySearch(charArray, myChar) >= 0) {
  // Do the work
}
```

**edit** An alternative that avoids using the `Arrays` module is to put the characters into a string (at initialization time) and then use [String.indexOf()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29):

```
String chars = "\uE001...";
...
if (chars.indexOf(myChar) >= 0) {
   // Do the work
}
```

This is not hugely different to what you're doing already, except that it requires less code.

If `n` is the size of `charArray`, the first solution is `O(log n)` whereas the second one is `O(n)`.

Comment: Unfortunately `Arrays` not available in Java ME.

Comment: Weeelll... `indexOf` does the same thing with the loop in the string. It does this `if(this.charAt(k) == ch) return k;`.

Comment: Is making it a string and using `indexOf(char)` too slow or otherwise inappropriate in this case? Otherwise, that would be the best option

Answer (score 1):

You can use hash/map to check existance of the characer. This approach has better time of O(log n) or O(1) depending on hash/map inner structure.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have access to Arrays, since you are working in JavaME, then you should try to:

- Or implement a sorted array and the binary search youself
- Or just use a O(n) solution, wich is a good solution anyways.

Your solution is O(n), along with the one stated by aix.

You could try to use a Map, but it would depends on how much elements you are in your array. If you think there won't be more than 1000 elements in the array, just use a O(n) solution. But if you think you could have an unkown number of elements, a Map would be a reasoable choice, providing a better solution.

Comment: An O(n) is a solution that provides an answer within a maximum of n steps, where n is the number of objects you have. In this case, n would be the size of the array. For example, if your array has 570 elements, the answer here will come off at the maximum of 570 iterations of your algorithm.  O(n) solutions are normally good, but if you have a large N (1k+), you could try to improve it. But it all depends on your business.If you will search a lot, but won't include much, a binary search in a sorted array with a O(log n) would be perfect. Otherwise consider using a Map.

Comment: Or if you really want to look into this, you could implement all those solutions and profile your applicattion to see what's the best. But of course the Map and the Binary Search in a Sorted array will probally be the faster ones for a large N, but sometimes it's not worth to waste so much time looking into something if you don't know how big N will be. In such cases, I would stick to the Map.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `net.rim.device.api.util.Arrays.getIndex(char[] array, char element)`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what [Java ME configuration / profile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_ME) you are using. If you're on CDC then check for what parts of Java SE 1.3 Collections framework are supported (just find javadocs targeted for your device and look in `java.util` package). Another thing worth checking is whether your device has some blackberry-specific API extensions to work with collections.

If you are limited to bare minimum of CLDC/MIDP then other solution than you mentioned would be to add chars to Vector and use [Vector.contains(Object)](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/java/util/Vector.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29)

Answer (score -2):

If you don't want to implement it yourself you could use ArrayUtils in apache commons project:

[ArrayUtils apache-commons](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#indexOf%28char%5B%5D,%20char%29)

Comment: Ignore this answer didn't see it was for black-berry ME.